# Can I use the WP_List_Table class to render tables on a page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently using shortcodes to display a list of items obtained from a table and displaying it on a page of my website but since the list of information is very large, I want to add a page and in the future a small filtering menu for the records.

I found the [WP_List_Table](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) class in the worpdress documentation which, from what I understood, is a class that allows you to create tables with a list of elements but I have also read in some tutorials like [this](https://clearintelligence.mx/wp-list-table-una-guia-paso-a-paso/) or [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-admin-tables/) one in which they indicate that this class is used to create a list of elements but for the wordpress admin.

**Can I use this class normally in the function my shortcode will render? Or is there any other class that is more appropriate, taking into account the functionalities that I wish to add in the future?**

The function and the shortcode that I use to render the information is this:

```
function opt_menu_cactaceas_frontend() {

    global $wpdb;
    $tabla_cactaceas = $wpdb->prefix . 'cactaceas2';
    $aspirantes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla_cactaceas");

    //echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead><tr><th width="70%">Nombre Cientifico</th><th width="30%">Imagen</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody id="the-list">';

    foreach ( $aspirantes as $aspirante ) {

        $genero = esc_textarea($aspirante->genero);
        $especie = esc_textarea($aspirante->especie);
        $subespecie = esc_textarea($aspirante->subespecie);
        $autor = esc_textarea($aspirante->autor);

        if ( $subespecie == '' ):

            $nombreCactacea = "<i>$genero $especie</i> $autor";
        else: 
            $nombreCactacea = "<i>$genero $especie</i> subsp. <i>$subespecie</i> $autor";

        endif;

        $imagen_cactus = wp_get_attachment_image( 263, 'thumbnail' );

        echo "<tr><td><a href='#' title='$motivacion'>$nombreCactacea</a></td><td>$imagen_cactus</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}

//funcion - agrega el shortcode en la pagina que se le llame
add_shortcode('srt_code_add_list_cactaceas', 'formulario_registro');
```

The table so far is rendered like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WP_List_Table class can be used on the frontend. However, the CSS for the WP admin may conflict with the CSS used on the frontend.

**Frontend**

[image]

The WP plugin contains 2 PHP files.

**bxft-shortcode.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * BXFT - Shortcode
 *
 * @package     BXFT\Shortcode
 *
 * Plugin Name: BXFT - Shortcode
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: Creating a shortcode with WP_List_Table.
 * Version:     1.0
 * Author:      Box
 * Author URI:  box@boxoft.net
 * License:     GPLv2
 */

add_shortcode( 'bxft-table', 'bxft_table_shortcode' );

function bxft_table_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class-bxft-table.php';
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $template;
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bxft_queue_stylesheet' );

function bxft_queue_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bxft-table-shortcode-style', admin_url( 'css/wp-admin.css' ), array(), '1.0' );
}
```

**class-bxft-table.php**

```
<?php
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';
}

class BXFT_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    public function prepare_items() {
        $data         = $this->wp_list_table_data();
        $per_page     = 8;
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items  = count( $data );
        $this->set_pagination_args(
            array(
                'total_items' => $total_items,
                'per_page'    => $per_page,
            )
        );

        // $this->items           = $data;
        $this->items           = array_slice(
            $data,
            ( ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page ),
            $per_page
        );
        $columns               = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden                = $this->get_hidden_columns();
        $this->_column_headers = array( $columns, $hidden );
    }

    public function wp_list_table_data() {
        $data = array(
            array(
                'id'    => 1,
                'name'  => 'Dilan',
                'email' => 'deverleighj@pen.io',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 2,
                'name'  => 'Tanner',
                'email' => 'tfleischeri@a8.net',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 3,
                'name'  => 'Darrell',
                'email' => 'dspurh@pen.io',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 4,
                'name'  => 'Dudley',
                'email' => 'droistoneg@umn.edu',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 5,
                'name'  => 'Merrili',
                'email' => 'mnutbeanf@tmall.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 6,
                'name'  => 'Brana',
                'email' => 'bcasonee@craigslist.org',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 7,
                'name'  => 'Susannah',
                'email' => 'sgolsbyd@netvibes.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 8,
                'name'  => 'Darcey',
                'email' => 'dpithiec@cmu.edu',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 9,
                'name'  => 'Sofie',
                'email' => 'sbroskeb@ca.gov',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 10,
                'name'  => 'Joscelin',
                'email' => 'jwestripa@php.net',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 11,
                'name'  => 'Kalila',
                'email' => 'kmacavaddy9@xing.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 12,
                'name'  => 'Marie-jeanne',
                'email' => 'mcocci8@1und1.de',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 13,
                'name'  => 'Darnell',
                'email' => 'dlamborne7@linkedin.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 14,
                'name'  => 'Hugibert',
                'email' => 'hhelgass6@icio.us',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 15,
                'name'  => 'Anitra',
                'email' => 'alongforth5@cmu.edu',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 16,
                'name'  => 'Reinaldos',
                'email' => 'rburchett4@simplemachines.org',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 17,
                'name'  => 'Arlan',
                'email' => 'adelph3@homestead.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 18,
                'name'  => 'Harwell',
                'email' => 'hturbefield2@sciencedaily.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 19,
                'name'  => 'Mikey',
                'email' => 'mmoakes1@reuters.com',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 20,
                'name'  => 'Mira',
                'email' => 'mmaciocia0@newsvine.com',
            ),
        );

        return $data;
    }

    public function get_hidden_columns() {
        return array( 'id' );
    }

    public function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'id'     => 'ID',
            'name'   => 'Name',
            'email'  => 'Email',
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'id':
            case 'name':
            case 'email':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return 'N/A';
        }
    }
}

function display_bxft_table() {
    $bxft_table = new BXFT_Table();
    $bxft_table->prepare_items();
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php $bxft_table->display(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

display_bxft_table();
```

I'm learning WP_List_Table by watching https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT9miexWCpPWD3BOrqHmwaXL2LLVb6kpg. Thanks for the author.

Answer (score 1):

The [WP_List_Table](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) mainly used for WordPress backend. If you want to render the table and want to look as same as the backend, then make sure that you have included proper resources like the admin does (eg. list-tables).
Otherwise, you can use bootstrap data-table as well or you can try below plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/